# Error al convertir a ISOString en javascript

Tags: javascript

Estoy tratando de pasar una fecha a formato ISODate usando el método toISOString() de javascript, el problema es que me convierte mal la hora.

```js
var fecha_hora = '2017-05-15 15:39:22'
var f = new Date(fecha_hora);
var fechaISO = f.toISOString();
console.log('fecha_hora:' + fecha_hora + '\nfecha_ISO:'+fechaISO);
```

me imprime la siguiente cadena:

```
`fecha_hora:2017-05-15 15:39:22
fecha_ISO:2017-05-15T20:39:22.000Z`
```

Comment: la hora es la misma el problema es por el UTF

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tu problema es que te falta agregar el `UTC` ,si no colocas te lo actualiza con la diferencia horaria que se encuentra el navegador del cliente
con respecto al `UTC`

> UTC significa Coordinated Universal Time (UTC) en español tiempo
>   universal coordinado [wiki](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiempo_universal_coordinado)

El ejemplo a continuacion:

```js
var fecha_hora = '2017-05-15 15:39:22 UTC'
var f = new Date(fecha_hora);
var fechaISO = f.toISOString();
console.log('fecha_hora: ' + fecha_hora + '\n fecha_ISO: '+fechaISO);
```

Comment: entonces podría concluir que estoy a 5 horas de diferencia de UTC?

Comment: eso es correcto