# Saber que fecha es mayor en Javascript

Tags: javascript, date

tengo 2 fechas, una de inicio y otra de fin, intento evitar que la de inicio sea mayor que la de fin, aparte de que no consigo hacerlo, me salen años raros, días que no son... etc.

```
                    console.log("start ", m , d ,  y);
                    console.log("fin ", m2 , d2, y2);

                    console.log("-------");

                    console.log("start", new Date(m, d, y));
                    console.log("fin", new Date(m2, d2, y2));

                    if (new Date(m, d, y) > new Date(m2, d2, y2)) {
                        format = false;
                        this.errorServer = true;
                        this.message = "La fecha de inicio no puede ser mayor que la fecha de fin.";
                    }
```

Y el resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como resultado de este cambio,  no me da el error de que la fecha de inicio es mayor...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Estás usando mal el constructor, lo correcto es:

new Date(anyo, mes, dia);

Pero no sólo eso, sino que el mes empieza en 0, luego réstale 1:

```js
console.log("start", new Date(2018, 10, 6)); //ayer, a día de la creación de esta respuesta.
console.log("fin", new Date()); //ahora

console.log(new Date(2018, 10, 6) > new Date());
console.log(new Date(2018, 10, 6) < new Date());
```

No sólo el formato es un poco extraño, sino que además es siempre hora UTC, por lo que la primera línea de la consola a mí me muestra `"2018-11-05T23:00:00.000Z"` porque estoy en UTC+1, luego la fecha 2018-11-06 (00:00:00) se ha retrasar una hora.

Comment: aqui te dejo una [respueta relacionada con el UTC](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/86790/28035)

Answer (score 1):

El problema lo tienes constructor para el objeto fecha que debe ser **new Date(anio, indiceMes, dia)** donde **indiceMes** debe ser indexado de 0 a 11.

Los operadores estandar `>`, `<`, `<=` o `>=` pueden ser usados normalmente para comparar el tipo **Date**, sin embargo si deseas utilizar los operadores `==`, `!=`, `===`, y `!==` debes convertir la fecha a milisegundos utilizando el metodo getTime().

```
var f1 = new Date();
var f2 = new Date(f1);
var iguales = f1.getTime() === f2.getTime();
var noIguales = f1.getTime() !== f2.getTime();
```

[Documentacion Oficial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date#Methods)